# Problem reducing over string

Tags: string

I wanted to define a function that removes all spaces from a given string:

```lisp
(defun remove-whitespace (raw-string)
  (cl-reduce (lambda (acc char)
               (if (equal " " (char-to-string char))
                   acc
                 (concat acc char))) raw-string :initial-value " "))
```

However, evaluating `(remove-whitespace "hello world")` results in:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep 104)
  concat(" " 104)
  (if (equal " " (char-to-string char)) acc (concat acc char))
  (lambda (acc char) (if (equal " " (char-to-string char)) acc (concat acc char)))(" " 104)
  cl-reduce((lambda (acc char) (if (equal " " (char-to-string char)) acc (concat acc char))) "hello world" :initial-value " ")
  remove-whitespace("hello world")
```

This is odd because the char code 104 must have been converted to a string by `char-to-string`. What am I missing?

**Self-answer**: It should have been (concat acc (char-to-string char)), not just (concat acc char).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(defun remove-whitespace (raw-string)
  (cl-reduce (lambda (acc char)
               (if (equal ?\s char)
                   acc
                 (concat acc (char-to-string char)))) raw-string :initial-value ""))
```

---

### OR

```lisp
(defun remove-whitespace (raw-string)
  (cl-reduce (lambda (acc char)
               (if (equal " " (char-to-string char))
                   acc
                 (concat acc (char-to-string char)))) raw-string :initial-value ""))
```

---

NOTE that `char` is an integer, therefore you can't concat it.

Comment: You're right! It was a simple type error.

Answer (score 4):

```
 (replace-regexp-in-string " " "" "Hello world")
```

Comment: Note that starting in emacs-28 you're be able to use 'string-replace' if you just want to replace a fixed string with another fixed string